# Is there a usable DNS for 192.168 range?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm looking for a existing DNS names pointing to 192.168.x.x. I need to set-up virtual host in our intranet and I can't change "hosts" file on the client.

Something like:

```
*.1-1-168-192.example.com
```

I know that I can make one with dyndns, but I'm looking for **existing one** with no set-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, but anything you might find would be erroneous records because these IPs are not routed publicly on the Internet (see [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)).  Even if you had one that worked, you would be piggy-backing on someone else's record just like using images hosted on another website.  That person could just change the record (or image) at any time, and it would affect you.

Your best bet for this, if you can't change the hosts file, is to run your own DNS server in your intranet.  Run something on your router if it can do this, or even set up a small Linux box running [BIND](http://www.isc.org/software/bind).

Comment: Further, some DNS resolvers will return NXDOMAIN when the record resolves to a reserved IP (Google notably).

Comment: @ChrisS Your comment is either inaccurate or outdated. I just created a DNS record pointing to a 172.16.0.0/12 address, and when I query 8.8.8.8 for that address I do get the A record.

Comment: I'm running dig with +trace right now, and at some point I get: ;; Received 122 bytes from 192.52.178.30#53(k.gtld-servers.net) in 114 ms
Which is what brought me here. Why does the ns server have a nonroutable IP?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set up your own. It might be as simple as configuring the existing DNS server functionality on your SOHO router if you have a small network, or indeed using a DynDNS service.

Answer (score 1):

The DNS for the RFC 1918 address blocks (192.168.0.0/16, etc) are served on the internet by the [AS112 project](http://public.as112.net/).

These are a large set of anycasted DNS servers explicitly designed to provide *negative* responses to all reverse (PTR) lookups in those address blocks.

They exist primarily to ensure that the root DNS servers do not get overloaded with these queries.

Comment: The link is dead. But from your description it sounds like the exact opposite of what was asked for. What was asked for was positive forward records. What you talk about is negative reverse records. As far as overloading the root with queries for private address blocks goes, I am wondering why they don't just point glue records for those ranges to private address blocks as well.

Comment: @kasperd the point of my answer is to demonstrate that _no such positive records exist_.   As for your second point, doing so would (eventually) cause all such queries to timeout, rather than have them immediately receive the (correct) negative response.

Comment: The non-existence of reverse records does not prove the non-existence of forward records. You can be almost certain such forward records do exist somewhere. Anybody who has a domain can create forward records pointing to any IP address of their choosing including private addresses, so of course such records exist.

Comment: @kasperd ah, yes, didn't realise he was looking for forward (`A`) records rather than `PTR` records.